# How to force network operator selection once and for all?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, 3g, data-connection

I'm using HTC Desire running stock Android 2.2 (with HTCs enhancements). There's a network operation selection in Settings / Wireless & netwokrs / Mobile networks / Network operators, which allows to "Search networks" (and thus select one operator manually) or "Seleect automatically" (which would probably connect to anything it will find).

There are 3 major cellular network operators in my region currently and they allow inter-operator roaming, but for a huge roaming fee. I want to avoid this huge fee by manually forcing selection of operator once and for all. It seems to work if I select my operator (say, "Operator A") in "Search networks" mode mentioned above, and it kind of works - until I travel underground and GSM module faces following situations sequentially:

- Operators A, B, C are available (on surface) => using preferred "operator A" and everything's ok
- We move in the subway, no GSM network is available at all => everything's ok, it shows that network is not available
- We start to emerge on the surface, and "operator B" becomes available, while "operator A" (preferred one) does not. Device stops execution of whatever was running and pops up annoying menu to "choose" new connection opportunity - "operator B". One can dismiss this menu with "Return" button, it as situation slowly changes and more operators become available, this menu would pop up a few more times.

So, the question is - how do I force mobile operator selection once and for all, and disable that extremely annoying (interruping currently running activities) popup menu with recently found cellular connections?

**UPDATE:** I'm using GSM / GPRS / EDGE / 3G (HSDPA) networks and in fact question refers to both voice and data traffic, so restricting APN probably has nothing to do with it. Normally, concurrent operators in the same region don't allow to roam through each other, so this problem probably doesn't exist for most normal users.

Comment: I've got a CDMA phone so I'm sure our options are different but I do have two that look like they'd be helpful to you.  I can toggle data roaming, and I can set my roaming mode to "Home only".  Do you have any options like this?  Also, are you talking about just Data or voice too?

Comment: "I'm using HTC Desire running stock Android 2.2 (with HTCs enhancements)" sad to say that might be your problem right there. CyanogenMod has options to disallow roaming, and it seems to allow you to force a provider (although granted I only get one choice, AT&T)

Answer (score 2):

[APN Lock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apn-lock-%28chr%29/pl.chrsoft.apnlock) may work.  It appears to give you the ability to block certain networks APN's which won't affect your ability to use Voice or SMS but won't allow your phone to make a data connection with the networks you block (by changing the APNs so you phone fails to connect).  I'd be careful though, messing with the APNs can cause problems this app doesn't have any comments yet.

Comment: I don't think it will work, as I don't have problems with APNs specifally: in fact, I have only 2 APNs (one for generic internet communication and other for MMSes) and I don't need any "locking" with them. I've clarified that question refers to both voice and data cellular transfer now.