# Network operator selection

Tags: 2.1-eclair, networking

I own a Acer BeTouch E130 upgraded to Android 2.1 (official upgrade).

And I'm facing issues with it, I'm basically from Belgium but I work in France currently therefor everyday I spend time in both France and Belgium. When I reach France, my phone selects a French network operator... okay sounds correct.

But now when I get home it doesn't switch to my operation (called **Mobistar**) it keep showing the French one (**Orange F**). Yesterday, while I was home in Brussels, I went to the network op settings and manually selected Mobistar in the list... It kept showing Orange F....
Is this a bug ? the french operator isn't even available in Belgium so it's impossible to connect to... And the weirdest thing, when I'm in France data sync can't be done because I disabled roaming... What the hell?

Any guess?

Comment: We remove greetings and signatures just out of stack exchange convention. You will not look rude by not having these.

Comment: It's not necessarily a mod. Any user with over 2k reputation can edit any question or answer. ANY user can suggest edits to questions that are then vetted.

Comment: You might also have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: You should also see Jeff's latest blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/ One of the things we can contact users about is if they constantly use greetings and signatures. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Bad form deleting your comments and vandalizing your question. Please don't do that.

Comment: I don't care either way about the hello/thanks argument in general but "Hi Dear" strikes me as a very odd greeting to use with people you don't know.  It's the kind of greeting used by elderly women when talking to their young relatives.

Comment: @Miloud:  I understand that being edited can be frustrating and it's normally considered bad form in a discussion forum, however, this is not a discussion forum.  As our FAQ states: "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."  I have to agree with Al, please review the links he has shared as well as the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).  Our intention is not to be rude, it's to be straight to the point.

Comment: @Miloud *Your edit* was rude and should not be in the question regardless.

Answer (score 2):

This previous question [How to force network operator selection once and for all?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/how-to-force-network-operator-selection-once-and-for-all) suggests that an app called [APN Lock](http://market.android.com/details?id=pl.chrsoft.apnlock) should allow you to lock your network to the correct one. You'd need to change the settings on it to change which network it locks to whenever you move between the countries, but hopefully you're not doing that every day?